# Add more then 7 time series to Morris.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, raphael, morris.js

Is it possible to show more then 7 time series (charts) on a single Morris.Line chart? Looks like there is a limitation of the library to 7 time series only. Is there any way to change the limit?

[image]

Comment: It definitely will be harder to read then

Comment: You could put a checkbox associated with each series (legend), and when the user click, you call the function that plot your chart, with the corresponding checkbox serie.